# Powershell: Get FQDN Hostname

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to retrieve the FQDN name of windows server via powershell script. I have found 2 solution so far:

```
$server =  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {hostname}
```

Above line will print just the short name of the server

```
$sysinfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
$server = “{0}.{1}” -f $sysinfo.Name, $sysinfo.Domain
```

Above two line will get me the FQDN but this looks really nasty code to retrieve just the hostname :(

So, My question is, is there an easier way to get the FQDN in powershell. I am a bash/perl coder and recently picked up powershell.. so finding it difficult.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of using invoke-command, you can do: $server = (hostname)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

How about: `"$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"`

This actually *only* works if the user is logged into a domain (i.e. no local accounts), logged into the same domain as the server, and doesn't work with disjointed name space AD configurations.

Use this as referenced in another answer:

```
$myFQDN=(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName+"."+(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain ; Write-Host $myFQDN
```

Comment: Hmm...so what does it mean to get the fully qualified domain name of a computer that isn't ON a domain? What do your answer output? Just the machine name? Your're saying my answer doesn't show your machine name even?

Comment: We have two domains so this won't work.  This method assumes the domain the PS script is running on, which may not be the case.

Comment: not working in powershell for me, better to go with answer posted by perilbrain

Comment: This fails if the user logged in is in a different domain from the computer.  It pulls the user's domain information, not the machine's

Comment: A shorter version of the same is `$myFQDN = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | %{ $_.DNSHostName + "." + $_.Domain}`

Answer (score 123):

To get FQDN of local computer:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName)
```

or

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).HostName
```

To get FQDN of Remote computer:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName('mytestpc1')
```

or

For better formatted value use:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName('mytestpc1').HostName
```

- For remote machines make sure host is reachable.

Comment: This is the correct way to get this information when running automation scripts. The $env:userdnsdomain returns NULL unless a user is logged in.

Comment: [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($env:computerName)).HostName

Comment: Looks like [`GetHostByName` is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostbyname?view=net-5.0), and the suggested method is to use `GetHostEntry` instead. i.e. [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($Env:ComputerName).HostName

Comment: This does not work anyways.  If you have an alternate domain name pointing to the machine that is *not* the AD FQDN, it will happily return that.

Answer (score 34):

Local Computer FQDN via dotNet class

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry([string]$env:computername).HostName
```

or

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry([string]"localhost").HostName
```

Reference:

[Dns Methods (System.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Dns_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

note: GetHostByName method is obsolete

---

Local computer FQDN via WMI query

```
$myFQDN=(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName+"."+(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
Write-Host $myFQDN
```

Reference:

[Win32_ComputerSystem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Nicely done. The `[string]` casts aren't necessary. A variant of the WMI command (updated for CIM) that only requires _one_ call: `Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem | % { $_.Name + '.' + $_.Domain }`

Answer (score 12):

This worked in PS and PS Core on Windows (Tested on Versions 5.1 and 7.2)

```
[System.Net.Dns]::Resolve($null).HostName
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName
```

`$env:computerName` returns NetBIOS name of the host, so that both previous examples return
netbioshostname.domainsuffix (not FQDN!)
instead of
dnshostname.domainsuffix (FQDN)

for example, host has
FQDN
aa-w2k12sv-storage.something.com
and NetBIOS name
aa-w2k12sv-stor (an easy case, I usually change NetBIOS name)

the hostname utility returns dnshostname, i.e., the first part of FQDN and code

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName
```

returns the right FQDN

Comment: never use the same NetBIOS and DNS names of AD domains and hosts. If your or 3rd party application writes to the log: "cannot connect to hostname.domainsuffix", what name it tries to resolve? If you see in the log "cannot connect to netbiosname.domainsuffix", no doubt, a lazy programmer added domain suffix to the NetBIOS name and you are sure, this is a bug, and can open a ticket to force them to fix the issue...

Answer (score 4):

It can also be retrieved from the registry:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' |
   % { $_.'NV HostName', $_.'NV Domain' -join '.' }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(Get-ADComputer $(hostname)).DNSHostName
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24064275).

Comment: I never understand the point to explain a single command. This is so picky. I guess its a robotic response?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the method that I've always used:

```
$fqdn= $(ping localhost -n 1)[1].split(" ")[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

to get the fqdn corresponding to the first IpAddress, it took this command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).AddressList[0]).HostName
WIN-1234567890.fritz.box
```

where `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).AddressList[0]` represents the first IpAddress-Object and `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress` gets the dns-object out of it.

If I took the winning solution on my standalone Windows, I got only:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName+"."+(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
WIN-1234567890.WORKGROUP
```

that's not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

## A cleaner format FQDN remotely

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName('remotehost').HostName
```

Comment: replace remotehost (leave the tics) with the hostname looked for and you will  get FQDN:
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName('lookedforserver').HostName

Comment: [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName('localhost').HostName

Answer (score 1):

I use the following syntax :

```
$Domain=[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($VM).Hostname.split('.')
$Domain=$Domain[1]+'.'+$Domain[2]
```

it does not matter if the $VM is up or down...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to determine the FQDN of a server based on the "Name" and "DistinguishedName". Works for multiple domains:

```
$server = Get-ADComputer serverName -Server domainName -Properties * | select Name, DistinguishedName
$domain = $server.DistinguishedName -split ","
$domain = $domain | ? {$_ -like 'DC=*'}
$domain = $domain -join "."
$domain = $domain -replace "DC="
$FQDN = $server.Name + "." + $domain
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one network adapter and more than one adapter is active (f.e WLAN + VPN) you need a bit more complex check. You can use this one-liner:

```bsh
[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress(([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses([System.Environment]::MachineName) | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork" } | Select-Object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString).HostName.ToLower()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$FQDN=[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($VM).Hostname.Split('.')
[int]$i = 1
[int]$x = 0
[string]$Domain = $null
do {
    $x = $i-$FQDN.Count
    $Domain = $Domain+$FQDN[$x]+"."
    $i = $i + 1
} until ( $i -eq $FQDN.Count )
$Domain = $Domain.TrimEnd(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following add.. I need to separate out the dns suffix from the hostname.. and I only "know" the servers alias shortname... and want to know what the dns suffix is

```
#example:
#serveralias:     MyAppServer.us.fred.com
#actualhostname:  server01.us.fred.com 
#I "know":        "MyAppServer" .. I pass this on as an env var called myjumpbox .. this could also be $env:computername


$forname                 = $env:myjumpbox
$fqdn                    = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($forname).Hostname
$shortname               = $fqdn.split('.')[0]
$domainname              = $fqdn -split $fqdn.split('.')[0]+"."
$dnssuf                  = $domainname[1]  
" name parts are- alias: " + $forname + " actual hostname: " + $shortname + " suffix: " + $dnssuf

#returns

name parts are- alias: MyAppServer actual hostname: server01 suffix: us.fred.com
```

Comment: this works for dns alias as well as "deep" domain names..

eg server01.us.fred.com with C-Name MyAppServer .. you can set $forname to "MyAppServer" and get shortname as well as domain name

Comment: Consider to delete it while editing and when ready you undelete... like this I'm hovering the dv and flag dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Resolve-DNSName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2022-ps) command this way works for **PowerShell 5.1** and **7.3** in my case.

```
(Resolve-DnsName -Name 'hostname').Name
```

### Supporting Resource

- [Resolve-DNSName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

  > **Description**
  >
  > The `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet performs a DNS query for the specified
  > name. This cmdlet is functionally similar to the nslookup tool which
  > allows users to query for names.

Answer (score 0):

The ADSystemInfo object can retrieve the DNS name of the local computer's domain:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME + '.' + [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("DomainDnsName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, (New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"), $null)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/iadsadsysteminfo-property-methods

Answer (score -2):

```
"$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"
```

will work if separated out like this

```
"$env:computername"+"$env:userdnsdomain"
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not accurate, as the user logon domain is not guaranteed to be the the same as the server domain, especially in a production environment, where the users can be declared in domain `example.net` but the servers be in `siteA.example.net`, `siteB.example.net`, `corp.example.net`, etc.

Comment: the $env:USERdnsdomain might also be empty if you run the script under a local user (like NTAUTHOITY\LOCAL_SERVICE)