# Powershell Script to Replace FQDN of that host in same file on multiple servers

Tags: powershell

Need some help as I am very new to PS.  I am looking for a script how to replace fqdn of remote host in specific file for multiple servers.  (Specific file is same in all servers)

Example:

```
(Get-Content C:\file.txt) |
      ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "locked/agent.name - XXX", "locked/agent.name - FQDN of the server"} |
      Set-Content c:\1.txt
```

Above script can be performed only one one host.  Can it be scripted to replace FQDN of individual host on the same file on many servers?

Request some help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'C:\file.txt'
$servers = Get-Content $file | % {$_ -replace "locked/agent.name - XXX", "locked/agent.name - FQDN of the server"}
$servers | Set-Content $file
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Hi Vladinir,  how can I input servers list where it contains many servers as I have already defined get-content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly (please update it directly with any clarifications):

Assuming you're running this on each sever, where the replacement string need only contain the local machine's FQDN, you can use a *variable* reference (or a reference to a variable from inside `"..."`, an expandable string) as the replacement operand:

```
# Get the local machine's FQDN - thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632876/45375
$fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('localhost').HostName

# Sample replacement
'>>locked/agent.name - XXX<<' -replace '(?<=locked/agent\.name - )XXX', $fqdn
```

If a given server's FQDN is `foo.example.org`, for instance, the above yields:

```
>>locked/agent.name - foo.example.org<<
```

Comment: Hello,  Thanks for addressing my issue.  However wanted to check can I execure on many servers or on only on the local host?  I have an scenario to execute and replace fqdn of that server in list of servers?  Please confirm.

Comment: My answer assumes that you run the same code on multiple servers, where the respective server's FQDN is used in the replacement; you could use `Invoke-Command` to send the command to all servers of interest. Unfortunately, I don't understand the description of your scenario. Can you update your question directly to clarify?

Comment: i am calling get-contect c:\temp\servers.txt (where it has all list of servers)

Comment: Pls ignore my previous comment.. I am using below script, I will come back if any errors.$file = 'C:\file.txt' #List of Servers  #
$fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('localhost').HostName # Which will get FQDN of the local host # $servers = Get-Content $file | % {$_ -replace locked/agent.name - XXX<<' -replace '(?<=locked/agent.name - $fqdn)} # This line will replace FQDN next to locked/agent.name #
$servers | Set-Content $file # This line commit changes #